# Add-AzureAccount : user_realm_discovery_failed: User realm discovery failed: Unable to connect to the remote

Tags: powershell, azure

I have an hero PowerShell script that attempts a connection to Azure:

```
$username = "asdfasdf"
$password = "asdfasdf"
$secstr = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.SecureString
$password.ToCharArray() | ForEach-Object {$secstr.AppendChar($_)}
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $secstr
Add-AzureAccount -Credential $cred
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionId asdfasdf
```

But I receive this error:

```
Add-AzureAccount : user_realm_discovery_failed: User realm discovery failed: Unable to connect to the remote 
server
At line:6 char:1
+ Add-AzureAccount -Credential $cred
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Add-AzureAccount], AadAuthenticationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Profile.AddAzureAccount
```

My user is definitely a co-administrator for the Azure Directory. Do I have to use a proxy to communicate with Azure?

Comment: Could you login your Azure account on Portal?

Comment: Yes I could log in that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice that you could logon your account on Azure Portal. Based on my knowledge, I don't this is Azure's issue. Maybe you could try to following cmdlet.

`$azureAccountName ="<your Azure AD Application ID"
$azurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "<your strong password>" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($azureAccountName, $azurePassword)
Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $cred`

I test in my lab. It works for me.
[image]

Comment: @santafebound You also could logon ARM mode by using `Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $cred`

Answer (score 8):

Hmm, this seems to be a common error for a variety of reasons. I had the wrong form of a username when trying to connect to service fabric and got the error:

> user_realm_discovery_failed: User realm discovery failed

i.e. `somedomain\fred` should have been `fred@somedomain.com`.

Once I corrected that it worked fine.  So given the answers above it appears that this this error exhibits for connection or authentication issues.

Answer (score 3):

```
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

Comment: This was it in my case !

Comment: Well this was in my case too. Thanks for your info

Answer (score 0):

This problem is due to targetframework in webconfig. i did changes below and it works.it wont work on 4.8 framework

```
<system.web>
    <!--<authentication mode="None" />-->
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" />
  </system.web>
```